# What are the citation styles used in these articles?

Tags: computer-science, citation-style

I am a CS student, and journals I think of submitting my article to recommend to use IEEE, ACM or APA on their websites. However, I read some of their articles and in their references, the do not use these citation styles. An obvious difference is that they put the year in the end. Have a look at some examples:

Article A:

> Pinto, L., Gandhi, D., Han, Y., Park, Y.L., Gupta, A.: The
> curious robot: learning visual representations via physical
> interactions. In: ECCV (2016)

Article B:

> Tripathi, A., Klami, A.,
> Oresic, M., and Kaski, S. Matching samples of multiple views. *Data
> Mining and Knowledge Discovery*, 23(2):300-321, 2011.

Article C:

> Paulina Hensman and David Masko. The impact of imbalanced training
> data for convolutional neural networks. Degree Project in Computer
> Science, *KTH Royal Institute of Technology*, 2015.

Of course, on the articles, some parts are in italic. I am very confused about this, any suggestions?

Comment: If you know what venue the paper was published in, you could search for their LaTeX template, which should provide details on the format.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please mention the titles of the journals for which you want to submit a paper, otherwise it's difficult to answer your question. It is somewhat common for a journal to use a modified version of a reference style such as IEEE. If you are unsure what to do, either send an email to the journal in question to ask for clarification, or just imitate the same reference style that you saw printed in the actual paper. Italic text is normally used for journal titles, book titles and proceedings titles (double-check each journal's guidelines for more info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some systems, *italics* are used to show that the referred text is a book rather than a journal, and in those cases you will also see the title of the chapter within the book as normal non-italicised text.

The IEEE style is to show the bibliography with the 'year at the end'.  The in-text citation format and that of the bibliography list, are different.

[IEEE REFERENCE GUIDE (.pdf)](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE-Reference-Guide-Online-v.04-20-2021.pdf)